# what are the external and native functions seen when i check cpu usage by visual studio debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cpu-usage, visual-studio-debugging

This is a screenshot of the recorded CPU profile

[image]

I was checking the CPU usage of my C# program using visual studio debugger.
But I am unable to understand what is external function, native function, and what is the difference between total CPU% and self CPU%.
I want to just analyze the CPU performance of my program

Comment: Next time post the actual picture of the thing you want to show, not the whole desktop picture inside a word in a whole desktop picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**external function** means system and framework functions that are executed by your code. External code functions start and stop the app, draw the UI, control threading, and provide other low-level services to the app.

**native function** is written in the computer's `native machine language and executed directly by the processor. It will not "host" the memory, and the memory will not be released for you, such as C++. And the CPU usage can detect it.

> and what is the difference between total CPU% and self CPU%.

**total CPU%**

> The milliseconds and CPU percentage used by calls to the function, and
>   functions called by the function, in the selected time range.

And **Total CPU** indicates how much work was done by the function and any functions called by it. High total CPU values point to the functions that are most expensive overall.

**self CPU%**

> The milliseconds and CPU percentage used by calls to the function in
>   the selected time range, excluding functions called by the function.

**Self CPU** indicates how much work was done by the code in the function body, excluding the work done by functions that were called by it. High Self CPU values may indicate a performance bottleneck within the function itself.

You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2019#analyze-the-cpu-usage-report) and [Measure application performance by analyzing CPU usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019) for more detailed info.